# VBA Edit SharePoint Discussion Post (PostItem) and Update Web Discussion

Tags: vba, sharepoint, outlook

I have a SharePoint discussion board sycned to Outlook 2010.

I want to be able to programmatically modify my posts within a SharePoint Discussion Board within Outlook VBA and have these changes reflected on the online discussion board.

The below code works in a test case to modify the items on the Outlook side but it is not synchronizing with SharePoint.

```
Private Sub modifySharePointItem()

    Dim obj As Outlook.PostItem
    Set obj = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)

    obj.Body = obj.Body + "test addition"
    obj.Save
    obj.Post

End Sub
```

I am assuming I need to not just `Save` and `Post` but an additional "synchronize" type command but I do not know what it is.

Reading about the data model for `PostItem` was basically useless unfortunately and none of the methods seemed to do what I was interested in.

---

I found out (by accident.....) I am able to delete posts from Outlook - so I can obviously get much of the way here, but I still am unsure how to sync the lists when items are modified.

Comment: It is depressing to google search something and find a StackOverflow question which is perfect to what I want to do, only to realize it was a tumbleweed question I posted myself...

Comment: lol it happened to me before

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Client Object Model to do modifications and editing in Sharepoint. I do it all the time. Since Outlook 2010 compiles down to the CLI you could use the Client Object Model dlls to do what you need. I have a whole bunch of C# code that I could share if you need it. This is what I used to get started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247(v=office.14).aspx

I hope that helps!